# Is there a way to enable fixed-point calculations in Box2D?

Tags: c++, server, box2d, game-physics, deterministic

I am using Box2D for a game that communicates to a server and I need complete determinism. I would simply like to use integer math/fixed-point math to achieve this and I was wondering if there was a way to enable that in Box2D.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Albeit with a fixed-point implementation and with modifications to the Box2D library code.

The C++ library code for Box2D 2.3.2 uses the `float32`-type for its implementation of real-number-like values. As `float32` is defined in `b2Settings.h` via a `typedef` (to the C++ `float` type), it can be changed on the one line to use a different underlying implementation of real-number-like values.

Unfortunately some of the code (like `b2Max`) is used or written in ways that break if `float32` is not defined to be a `float`. So then those errors have to be chased down and the errant code rewritten such that the new type can be used.

I have done this sort of work myself including writing my own fixed-point implementation. The short of this is that I'd recommend using a 64-bit implementation with between 14 to 24 bits for the fractional portion of values (at least to make it through most of the Testbed tests without unusable amounts of underflow/overflow issues). You can take a look at [my fork](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/Box2D) to see how I've done this but it's not presently code that's ready for release (not as of 2/11/2017).

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can achieve determinism in Physics Engine, is to use a Fixed Time step update on the physics engine. You can read more information in this link. http://saltares.com/blog/games/fixing-your-timestep-in-libgdx-and-box2d/

Comment: I do use a fixed time step for determinism overall.. but apparently that might not be enough because of the problem of floating-point determinism across different devices (different compilers treat floating point numbers differently and so forth).